# Creating a sheaf out of cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I have been learning about the cohomology of sheaves, and I have the following questions.

Suppose we have a sheaf $\mathscr{F}\in Sh_X$ where $X$ is some topological space. Now, for any open $U\subset X$, we have a map $\mathscr{F}\to j_*\mathscr{F}|_U$ (where $j:U\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion) induced by the restriction maps. Now $H^0(X,j_*\mathscr{F}|_U) = H^0(U,\mathscr{F}|_U)$. As a result, we have a map of cohomologies $H^i(X, \mathscr{F})\to H^i(U,\mathscr{F} |_U)$. Now, as far as I can see, it is easy to conclude that we have a presheaf $\scr{G}$, given by
\begin{align*}
U\mapsto H^i(U,\mathscr{F}|_U)
\end{align*}
for each $i\ge 0$.

Now, what I am unsure about are the following points:

1. Is $\scr{G}$ a sheaf? I can't think of any way to prove that it is.
2. If $\scr{G}$ is not a sheaf, what is its sheafification? Are there are any well behaved cases where the sheafification is actually something nice?

I would be very grateful is someone helps me out. Thank you.

Comment: It is a good exercise to prove that the sheafification of $\mathscr{G}$ is always zero (for $i>0$). So you can't really get something interesting out of it.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment. Do you think the following makes sense? I will show that all the stalks of $\mathscr{G}$ are 0. Let $\mathscr{I}$ be an injective such that $0\to \mathscr{F}\to \mathscr{I}\to \mathscr{F}/\mathscr{I}\to 0$ is exact. This means $0\to \mathscr{F}|_U\to \mathscr{I}|_U\to (\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{I})|_U\to 0$ is exact for each...

Comment: ...open $U\subset X$. Thus, we find that $0\to \mathscr{F}(U)\to \mathscr{I}(U)\to (\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{I})(U)\to H^1(U,\mathscr{F}|_U)\to 0$ is exact. Since direct limits preserve exactness, we have that $0\to \mathscr{F}_x\to \mathscr{I}_x\to (\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{I})_x\to \mathscr{G}_x \to 0$ is exact for each $x\in X$. We already have that $0\to \mathscr{F}_x\to \mathscr{I}_x\to (\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{I})_x \to 0$, whence we conclude that $\mathscr{G}_x \to 0$ is injective, and we are done.

Comment: This seems to work indeed. Another way to prove it : consider an injective resolution $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{I}^\bullet$ and forget that the $\mathscr{I}^i$ are sheaves. The cohomology in the category of presheaves is just $U\mapsto H^i(U,\mathscr{F})$ because limits and colimits are computed pointwise. (This btw shows that these presheaves are the derived functors of the forgetful functor $Sh(X)\to PSh(X)$. Now since sheafification is exact and thus commute with cohomology and since the $\mathscr{I}^i$ are sheaves, the sheafification of $U\mapsto H^i(U,\mathscr{F})$ is zero.